# Regular Expression to match any between ""

Tags: regex

The text is:

`"I like to watch.","\"I like to watch.\""`

I want break the text into "I like to watch." and "\"I like to watch.\""

use  "[\w\W]+?"

but get "I like to watch.","\",

What's the right expression?

Comment: Why not split it by `,`?

Comment: @MuratK.: You cannot split with a `,` here.

Comment: the text maybe "I like to watch."\n\t"\"I like to watch.\"" or any string between  "I like to watch." and "\"I like to watch.\""@MuratK.

Comment: @MuratK.: Nowhere can it be done by splitting with `,`, see, say: `"\"I know, it is \"not\" so easy","Look, another string"`
.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I see. Nvm then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxi5Yg/1).

**Details**:

- `"` - a double quote
- `[^"\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than a double quote and a backslash
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\\.` - a backslash and any char other than a line break char
  - `[^"\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than a double quote and a backslash
- `"` - a double quote

Comment: The `.`  can be replaced with `[\s\S]` if a DOTALL modifier is not available in your regex flavor.